# Web-app or software for novelty fake betting with friends

Tags: web-apps, app

I would like somewhere I can make up my own random/novelty bets with friends.

For example friends would join a group. a person could create a question like "will john score over 80% on the next test?", maybe even custom odds for the options, and then all the group can bet on it. After the bet deadline the person can select the answer that ended up correct and then whoever chose it gets paid out.

Should probably be fake money. Can be a web-app or software, but should be available for iOS and Android or Windows and macOS.